# Basic Angular Route Not Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Trying to get a simple angular route set up but the view/partial is not getting loaded, i.e. is not showing and does not appear in the network tab. I believe it is set up correctly and can't see what is causing this.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate','ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Main</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script src="bower_components\angular\angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components\angular-route\angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components\angular-animate\angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/assets/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="public/assets/js/controllers/main.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any ideas why it's not showing?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I am getting no console errors- my view is just a simple

I am getting to the page using an express route:

```
app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendfile("index.html", { root: __dirname + "/public" });
  });
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ft3GOe36koFxDRIGbqiD?p=preview so must be something else that is not clear from your example

Comment: Your code is just fine so your problem should be one of those 1. Forgot to create 'views/main.html' ? 2. Maybe your code does not run under web server Hope one of those works, happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had missed out ng-controller in my index.html page